# Bootstrap Glyphicons not showing locally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to load a Bootstrap buttons that has a Glyphicon, but the icon won't show. The button picks every other CSS attached to it except the icons. Is my approach wrong in any way?

[What I want >>>](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples):

[image]

What I get instead:

[image]

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="../../bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Center Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-center" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Right Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Justify"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you have shown here. Are you sure those file paths are correct? Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @DavidG Yes. I don't think the CSS would link correctly if they were wrong? Or would they?

Comment: Well do you have any errors?

Comment: Also as you are using a local copy of Bootstrap, have you also got the Glyphicon fonts locally too?

Comment: Yes. I do have them locally. Inside the fonts folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder structure you have is misconfigured as Boostrap expects the font files to exist in a folder one up and then down again in a folder called fonts, for example: `../fonts/xxxx`. So if you have the Bootstrap files in the root, that will not work. Move your Bootstrap files into their own directory so your structure looks something like this:

```
root
  ----bootstrap
    ----bootstrap.css
    ----bootstrap.js
  --fonts
    --glyphicons.*
```

Comment: I made it work by moving the HTML to the root. Please check out my update. I still have a small issue. Thanks for the responses so far.

Comment: You can't change your question once it has been asked.

Answer (score -1):

try requiring the jquery library before bootstrap, that what I did and it worked fine !

Comment: This is a purely styling issue, adding jQuery won't fix it.